# passing javascript variable into php wordpress

Tags: variables, query-variable

I am trying to pass variable from JS to PHP.
I have this JS code that runs in my footer.php:

```
<script>
function printResponse(response) {
    if ( response.errorCode == 0 ) {
        var NumberOfCommentsPerStream = response.streamInfo.commentCount;
        //alert(NumberOfCommentsPerStream);
    } else {
        alert('Error :' + response.errorMessage);
    }
}


var NoumberOfCommentsParams = {
    categoryID: "iphones_comments",
   streamID: '<?php the_ID(); ?>',
    callback:printResponse
};

gigya.comments.getStreamInfo(NoumberOfCommentsParams);
```

as you can see I have a variable there which counts my gigya comments:
**NumberOfCommentsPerStream**

it works fine when I am using alert. it shows the number of comments.
I would like to integrate it to wordpress so I can echo it and display it in wordpress
tried to simply echo it out:

```
<?php echo $NumberOfCommentsPerStream; ?>
```

of course it is not working. just trying to demonstrate what I am trying to achive
anyone has a clue?

Comment: If you just want to display it you could add a blank div with a unique id (eg `<div id="number_of_comments_per_stream"></div>`) to your template and then set this in your `printResponse` routine: `$('#number_of_comments_per_stream').html('Number of comments: ' + NumberOfCommentsPerStream);`

Comment: I am trying to implement it to my JS code but can't seem to understand  how to do it. I am kind of new to JS.. anyway you can give me a hint where exactly I need to put it in my JS code? Thanks!

Comment: Just after (or before!) where you have the commented-out `alert(NumberOfCommentsPerStream)`

Comment: I tried that and it looks reasonable but it didn't work.. I even tried to just regular HTML string and it didn't print it out. I will try one more thing and get back to you. thanks

Comment: Test to see if it's finding the `div`, either through the debugger or doing an `alert($('#number_of_comments_per_stream').length);` which should give `1`